# StructureMap reset singleton instance

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have created a bootstrapper which creates a singleton object.  Under some circumstances, I wish to have the singleton recreated... I have tried:
ObjectFactory.Model.For().EjectAndRemoveAll();

Does anyone know how I can remove current instances for a specific type, without removing the rules that govern its creation.  e.g. ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf will remove the config rules as well.

thanks for your help

Comment: Can I ask why you need to reset the singleton?  If the singleton has some internal state which requires a reset that might be a code smell , maybe it's something that should be per-request, rather than a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to [define a lifecycle by overriding ILifeCycle](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2010/08/structuremap-ilifecycle.html) which ejects the cached instance when your conditions are met.

You could start by looking at the implementation of the [singleton lifecycle in the structuremap source](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/Source/StructureMap/Pipeline/SingletonLifecycle.cs) and perhaps inherit or modify that.